# How to use simple html DOM for this table?

Tags: php, html, dom

hi everybody i want to dom a webpage and fetch data from it's table.
table code :

```
            <tbody>
                <tr class="sh" onclick="ii.ShowShareHolder('21711,IRO1DMOR0004')">
                    <td>person</td>
                    <td><div class="ltr" title="1,100,000">1 M</div></td>
                    <td>2.050</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td><div class=""></div></td>
                </tr>
            
                <tr class="sh" onclick="ii.ShowShareHolder('42123,IRO1DMOR0004')">
                    <td>person</td>
                    <td>953,169</td>
                    <td>1.780</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td><div class=""></div></td>
                </tr>
        </tbody>
```

this table has two kind of data bigger than 1M and smaller than 1M . i want to get the 1.100.000 td div data and 953.169 data on this table.
my code is below.it works fine for bigger than 1M data but i don't know how to get the smaller data on this table.

```
foreach ($tables as $table) {
    foreach ($table->find('tr') as $row) {
        foreach($row->find('div') as $div)
        {
            if(array_key_exists('title',$div->attr))
            {
                $data[] = str_replace(",","",($div->attr['title']));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check if the `<div title="">` exist. If true, get that value, else, get the value of the second `<td>`.

Here is an example using [SimpleXML](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php):

```php
$html = <<<HTML
    <tbody>
        <tr class="sh" onclick="ii.ShowShareHolder('21711,IRO1DMOR0004')">
            <td>person</td>
            <td><div class="ltr" title="1,100,000">1 M</div></td>
            <td>2.050</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td><div class=""></div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="sh" onclick="ii.ShowShareHolder('42123,IRO1DMOR0004')">
            <td>person</td>
            <td>953,169</td>
            <td>1.780</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td><div class=""></div></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
HTML;

// parse HTML
$xml = simplexml_load_string($html);

$data = [];

// For each <tr>
foreach ($xml->tr as $row) {

    // if not found, check the 2nd <td>
    $item = $row->children()[1];

    // check if a div with title exists
    if (isset($item->div['title'])) {
        $data[] = str_replace(',', '', $item->div['title']);
    }
    else { // else, take the content
        $data[] = str_replace(',', '', $item);
    }
}

var_dump($data);
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(7) "1100000"
  [1]=>
  string(6) "953169"
}
```

See the [live demo](https://3v4l.org/idndf).

Answer (score 0):

tnx man i use your code but it doesn't work and have many error.
this is my complete functions code.because the server is gzip encode i read with curl .

```
        $url = "http://tsetmc.com/Loader.aspx?Partree=15131T&c=IRO1DMOR0004";
    $curl = curl_get_data($url);
    if(!empty($curl) ){
        $html = str_get_html($curl);
        $xml = simplexml_load_string($html);
        var_dump($xml);
        $data = [];

        // For each <tr>
        foreach ($xml->tr as $row) {

            // check path `<td><div title="">`
            $result = $row->xpath('td/div[@title]');
            if (! empty($result)) {
                foreach ($result as $item) {
                    $data[] = str_replace(',', '', $item['title']);
                }
            }
            else {
                // if not found, check the 2nd <td>
                $result = $row->xpath('td[position()=2]');
                foreach ($result as $item) {
                    $data[] = str_replace(',', '', $item);
                }
            }
        }
        return $data;
    }
```